# How to merge xml app.config files outside of the build process

Tags: c#, xml, deployment, appsettings

I would like to use app.config files for settings, but I don't want to have to select different build configurations to select which settings to use, I would rather everything build in release and then just the app.config file be different when the application is deployed.

What is a good way to merge two xml files together so that I can deploy the correct settings to the correct environment? I have found several solutions that are based on selecting different build configurations and the transform happens at build time, but I want the transform to just be from a command line utility that my deploy script can run

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @SlyRaskal Thanks, I tried to reword the question to better describe the problem I'm trying to solve

Comment: You're welcome.  Hope you are able to find a resolution to your problem.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At my company, we use the [Web Config Transformation Runner](https://github.com/erichexter/WebConfigTransformRunner), available on GitHub. It may be invoked directly from the command line, a bit like this:

```
D:\Utils\WebConfigTransformRunner.exe App.config App.production.config App.config
```

We've incorporated this into a larger packaging and deployment process to handle deploying to our various environments.